# Passing json/data to a javascript object with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to get R to interact via shiny with other javascript elements, which I'm guessing means by having `server.R` serve a customised shiny object (ideally json formatted?) to `ui.R`, which is then converted to a javascript array.  My work-in-progress code is:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$species_table <- renderTable({ iris[iris$Species == input$species,] })
    output$json <- RJSONIO::toJSON(iris[iris$Species == input$species,], byrow=T, colNames=T) # error line
  }
)
```

**ui.R**

```
require(shiny)
specs = as.character(unique(iris$Species))
names(specs) = specs

pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("minimal json handling example"), 
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("species", "Species", specs)),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("species_table")
  )
)
```

Which returns the server error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside
 a reactive expression or observer.)
```

.. because it's obviously the wrong approach.  Without *server.R*'s line `output$json <- ...` the outcome works and [looks like this](https://geotheory.shinyapps.io/example1/), so the rest of the code is ok.  But I also want to get the json (or any alternative format) across somehow and trigger a subsequent javascript action to read it in as an array object.  Grateful for any pointers, and apologies in advance if my description is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, that error generally means that you need to wrap `reactive({})` around something, in this case your `toJSON`  command. This works, and displays the JSON data.

**ui.r**

```
require(shiny)
specs = as.character(unique(iris$Species))
names(specs) = specs

pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("minimal json handling example"), 
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("species", "Species", specs)),
  mainPanel(
    #tableOutput("species_table")
    textOutput("json")
  )
)
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$species_table <- renderTable({ iris[iris$Species == input$species,] })
    output$json <-reactive({ RJSONIO::toJSON(iris[iris$Species == input$species,], 
        byrow=T, colNames=T)  })# error line
  } 
)
```

Comment: Thanks John, will check this tomorrow.  Do you have any idea how I can get that read in as a javascript object somehow, so as to integrate with non-shiny scripting?

Comment: @geotheory You can add javascript using `tags$script(HTML())`. Check out the HTML tags and dynamic UI articles here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/ . Beyond that you may need to ask a new question with a specific example. Good luck.

Comment: Cracked it! Thanks vm John. Example below.

Answer (score 4):

For benefit of others this is the working formula.  If anyone can suggest a more elegant solution I'd be grateful.  Open the browser's javascript console log to see object 'data' being updated..

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
iris <- datasets::iris
names(iris) <- gsub('[/.]','_',tolower(names(iris)))

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$json <- reactive({
      paste('<script>data=', 
            RJSONIO::toJSON(iris[iris$species == input$species,], byrow=T, colNames=T),
            ';console.log(data[0]);', # print 1 data line to console
            '</script>')
    })
  }
)
```

**ui.R**

```
require(shiny)
iris <- datasets::iris
names(iris) <- gsub('[/.]','_',tolower(names(iris)))
specs <- as.character(unique(iris$species))
names(specs) <- specs

pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("minimal json handling example"), 
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("species", "Species", specs)),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("json")
  )
)
```